# Find a maximum of complex function

Tags: complex-numbers

I am  trying to find a simple method that does not use the tools of advanced differential calculus to  find  following maximum, whose existence is justified by the compactness of the close ball $\Delta$  of $\mathbb C$  and continuity of the function  $f:z \mapsto |z^3 + 2iz|$ from $\mathbb C$   to  $\mathbb C$

$$ \large { \displaystyle \max_{z \in {\mathbb C},|z| \leq 1} |z^3 +2i z |} $$
Since  : $$(\forall z \in \Delta) \quad  f(z) \leq  3 $$
is obtained using triangular inequality,  we can yet try to find some $z_0 \in {\mathbb C}$ such that $f(z_0)=3$

Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks.

Comment: That's a much better problem statement. It tells us that you have worked quite a bit on the problem, and already know a lot about it. Maybe with my hint you can polish it off.

Comment: @Steve D: I did not want to talk too much for my English (even beginners). @ Paul Slevin,Gerry Myerson, draks : Thank you for your reception and your instructions for using this nice site by which I edited my post. (and excuse my english)

Comment: A very, very simple method is asking [Wolfram](http://tinyurl.com/cp7jsor).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: when do you get equality in the triangle inequality?

Comment: @ Gerry Myerson : When the two terms are directely proportional. I well see this .

Comment: @ Gerry Myereson: Thank's for hint. Using it, i find that $z_0=\frac{\sqrt 2}{2} (1+i)$ gives $f(z_0)=3$

Comment: Well done! ${}$

Answer (score 5):

If you've begun a study of complex functions, you may have seen the [Maximum Modulus Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle).  Since $z^3 + 2iz$ is a polynomial and entire (analytic in the complex plane), the maximum of $|z^3 + 2iz|$ you seek must occur on the boundary of the unit disk.  Gerry's Hint then quickly points you in the right direction!

Comment: Ah, drat, you type faster +1

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $z^3 + 2iz$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{C}$ (i.e. holomorphic) so you can apply the [maximum modulus principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle), and deduce that the maximum of $f$ lies on the boundary of $\Delta$, which has a simple parametrisation, so you can use standard techniques from real one-variable calculus to find the maximum.

(A slightly different approach to Gerry Myerson's, much more complicated in this case but also far more general.)

Comment: @ hardmath and dbaupp : Thank you for the idea of maximum module principle.I was looking for a suitable method for beginning students. It turns out that the Pricipe gives the idea already! Thank you!